# Querying Unix Timestamp using JOOQ

Tags: mysql, unix, timestamp, jooq

I'm using a MySQL server, and I'm trying to retrieve a timestamp using the JOOQ API. However, I think the default JOOQ behavior returns the time in the local timezone, and not UTC (it's not using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. Using JOOQ, my query looks like

```
db.select(USER_TABLE.REGISTERED_ON)
    .from(USER_TABLE)
    .where(USER_TABLE.EMAIL.equal(email)
    .fetchAny()
```

However, the sql that I want to execute should be something like this

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(schema.table.timestamp_col)
    FROM schema.table
    WHERE email="someone@domain.com"
```

Is it possible using the JOOQ API? If not, what's the best way to run this query, because I really want to be able to use the generated code (USER_TABLE, USER_TABLE.REGISTERED_ON, etc).

**EDIT:** I'm now doing the following, but is it safe? Basically I'm removing the quotations from JOOQ's generated classes.

```
String timestamp_field = USER_TABLE.REGISTERED_ON.toString().replace("\"", "");
Field<?> f = DSL.field("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(" + timestamp_field + ")");
Record r = db.select(f)
    .from(USER_TABLE)
    .where(USER_TABLE.EMAIL.equal(email))
    .fetchAny();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to tackle this problem:

#### Use a `Converter` or `Binding` to convert the type

You can register a data type [`Converter`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/) or [`Binding`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/) in the source code generator. This way, the code generator will generate a `Field<YourType>` for every `TIMESTAMP` field in the database. Possible useful types are:

- `java.lang.Long`
- `java.time.Instant`
- `java.time.OffsetDateTime` (note that jOOQ 3.7 will support this via [#4338])[3](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/)

#### Use plain SQL

Use [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) every time you want to do an explicit conversion using the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function. Your solution works:

```
String timestamp_field = USER_TABLE.REGISTERED_ON.toString().replace("\"", "");
Field<?> f = DSL.field("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(" + timestamp_field + ")");
```

But it is not recommended because:

- You should *never* rely on any `toString()` implementation of any Java type.
- You should generally try to avoid string concatenation with jOOQ's plain SQL API

A better solution would be:

```
DSL.field("UNIX_TIMESTAMP({0})", Long.class, USER_TABLE.REGISTERED_ON);
```

Or even:

```
public static Field<Long> unixTimestamp(Field<Timestamp> arg) {
    return DSL.field("UNIX_TIMESTAMP({0})", Long.class, arg);
}
```

#### Use `BIGINT` in the database

You could of course use `BIGINT` or `BIGINT UNSIGNED` in the database instead of `TIMESTAMP`. This way, you will always automatically have the integer unix timestamp value. This is just a workaround for completeness's sake.